# Windows Domain accounts gets locked without any failed logon events

Tags: active-directory, user-accounts, eventviewer

I have a domain account which keeps getting locked without any prior wrong password login attempts:

I.e (completely stripped off the details, just to give you an idea)

10:15:49 - logon successful
10:16:55 - logon failed (account locked)

There's something very odd here: I would expect at least one event between a successful logon and failed logon due to locked password. Where's the event that causes the lock with a failed password?

Other information:

-It's a MS RemoteApp system: there's a remoteapp system where people login via a web portal. The authentication happens during people logging into the web portal.

-There's no genius who's randomly locking accounts, even that should be in the logs, amirite?

Comment: Are failed logins being logged across all domain controllers?

Comment: There's only one domain controller.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's [account lockout tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18465) might help you figure out what's going on.

> There's no genius who's randomly locking accounts, even that should be
>   in the logs, amirite?

Not necessarily.

Honestly, I kind of want to copy and paste Ryan Ries' answer [here](https://serverfault.com/a/547793/174813), so I'll link it instead.

My guess would be that someone has used their personal account for a service, but that's only a random guess.

Comment: I've used that tool too. It showed "0" failed attempts but the account was locked regardless. Go figure!